# Return Key Based on Range of Values in a TreeSet within Map

Tags: java, dictionary, integer, set

First post here and I'm very new to Java (and programming in general)!

I'm trying to understand how to manipulate Maps when they contain other collections. I'm trying to write code to store names as keys against values that are sets of Integers within a Map. I then want to be able to return the keys of any values that have elements that fall within a given range.

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> index = new TreeMap<>();
Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>;

numbers.add(80);
numbers.add(90);
numbers.add(100);
index.put("Adam", numbers);

numbers = new TreeSet<>();
numbers.add(30);
numbers.add(40);
numbers.add(50);
index.put("Eve", numbers);
```

I now have a Map with an entry with Key "Adam" and Value [80, 90, 100] and another entry with key "Eve" and Value [30, 40, 50]. At least I think I have!

I now want to be able to return the name of any key holding values that fall within a given range.

For example, if the range is 25  to 50 the return would be "Eve".
If the range is 50 to 85 the return would be both "Adam" and "Eve".

I thought containsValue() might work but doesn't (because of the Set?).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: without knowing anything about your problem domain:
have you considered the inverse - using the numbers as keys, and a Set of names as the value in your TreeMap?
That would seem to suit the way you're using it, given your description.

Comment: Thanks, you're question has just highlighted another problem. There may be duplicate values so I couldn't do what you suggest, but I also cannot use TreeSet. I'd need an ArrayList instead I think?

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates you'd use a Set instead of a List; and you'd use a Tree-based collection implementation (TreeMap, TreeSet) only if you need to have it sorted (by something that is comparable).
In general, first determine if you need a List, Set or Map and then see if the common ArrayList, HashMap or HashSet suffice. Only if they do not, consider using a Tree-based or LinkedList-based collection implementation.

Comment: I see. I want to permit duplicates so I'd need an ArrayList, but I also would like the values ordered so could I use Collections.sort(numbers)? I'll have to lookup HashMap and HashSet. Sorry, I did say I was new at this!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your desing the only way I can think of is to iterate through the map and every value set but it's not very efficient:

```
public Set<String> containsRange(Map<String, Set<Integer>> index, int lowerBound, int upperBound){
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Integer>> entry : index.entrySet()) {
        String string = entry.getKey();
        for (Integer integer : entry.getValue()) {
            if (integer >= lowerBound && integer <= upperBound) {
                result.add(string);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to accomplish this with any of the standard map methods. In particular, maps are very good for accessing things via key, but not via value.

I think in this case you would be better off creating a list of a custom object. The custom object would contain the list of values and the string. When you wanted to get all the strings with a value in that range, you'd iterate over the list and fill a new list with the ones that match.

Here's what it would look like:

```
List<RangedString> index = new ArrayList<RangedString>();
...
public List<String> getStringInRange(int low, int high) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (RangedString rangedString : index) {
        if (rangedString.inRange(low, high)) {
            results.add(rangedString.getString());
        }
    }
}
```

The `RangedString.inRange` method would look like this:

```
Set<Integer> values;
...
public boolean inRange(int low, int high) {
    for (Integer value : values) {
        if (value >= low && value <= high) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this Algorithm at first glance

1)Make a Hashset for storing the key results

2)Iterate thu map and then each elemnet of set.

3) Compare it with the input range.

4) If it lies there add it in hashset.

5)Thats it

Here using hashset as it will ensure unique key result.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like what I've been trying to do (without success). I've iterated through the map, then through each element of the set, compared each element against the input range giving me only the values that I need. Are you able to explain a little more on how I could use those values to put the associated keys into a Hashset?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom logic to iterate through the each set for each entry in the map and get the  corresponding key of the entry if it falls within the desired range.

Comment: Hi, I've tried iterating through each set for each entry in the map and can isolate the values that fall within the range. I'm just lost when it comes to getting the corresponding key(s)?